# How does the author get to his equation for the ellipse and the antenna's beam?

Tags: signal-processing, radar

I am trying to understand how the author of this textbook (*Basic Radar Analysis* by Mervin C. Budge) realizes the equation for the ellipse shown in the image attached labeled Figure 2.3 (found in Chapter 2).

In the text not shown here, it is stated that the length of the major axis of the ellipse is \$\small R{\theta_A}\$ and of the minor axis of the ellipse is \$\small R{\theta_B}\$. However, his equation for the ellipse which is a cross section of the beam formed by a radar antenna is as follows:
$$
A_{\text{ellipse}} = {\pi \over 4} \cdot R{\theta_A} \cdot R{\theta_B} \space (m^2)
$$
He then goes on to say that the beam is the same area as the ellipse, however, replacing the term \$\pi\over 4\$ with a scaling factor \$\small K_a\$ to allow for imperfections in the antenna's beam.

My specific questions are as follows:

- Where does the \$1\over 4\$ factor come from in his equation for the area of the ellipse? Is there a piece of radar analysis I am failing to see?
- Why is the ellipse's area (which is a cross section of the beam) the same as the area of the beam?
- Is \$\small R\theta\$ here phase-magnitude notation?

I am new to radar analysis so please word any answers accordingly. Thank you in advance for any help given.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the 1/4 factor come from in his equation for the area of the
> ellipse? Is there a piece of radar analysis I am failing to see?

If you plot an elliptical disk (in Mathematica);

```
reg = Disk[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]
```

where the semi-axes lengths are \$r_x\$ and \$r_y\$ or {2,1} respectively. Now if you format the graphic, you get the following image, with `b` representing the x-semi-axis and `a` representing the y-semi-axis.

[image]

The area for this ellipse would be \$\pi a b\$

---

If you look at the Figure 2.3 (that you attached), the distances labeled as the \$R \theta_a\$ and \$R \theta_b\$ are equal to twice the semi-axes.

Therefore, for a the elliptical disk shown in figure 2.3:

$$\text{reg2}=\text{Disk}\left[\{0,0\},\left\{\frac{r \theta _a}{2},\frac{r \theta _b}{2}\right\}\right]$$

The area would be:

$$\frac{1}{4} \pi  r^2 \theta _a \theta _b$$

That's where the 1/4 comes from.

Also search "area of ellipse" on Google.

---

> Why is the ellipse's area (which is a cross section of the beam) the
> same as the area of the beam?

It is an assumption. Look at equations (2.6) and (2.7) of the book. An empirical factor of \$K_a\$ is used instead.

---

> Is Rθ here phase-magnitude notation?

No, it is just the author's chosen way of writing \$R\$ times \$\theta\$. You remember the famous \$s=r \theta\$. More info can be found [here](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/trigonometry/radians/s=r-theta-formula-equation.php).

---

Answer (score 0):

Rθ is just the extent (length) of that axis of the ellipse in a particular direction, either along the major or minor axis.  I don't think it's supposed to be a phasor notation.

Answer (score 0):

The area of an ellipse can be expressed as pi times (semi-major axis) times (semi-minor axis). The factor of 4 comes about because \ R{\theta_A} \ is twice the semi-major axis and \ R{\theta B} \ is twice the semi-minor axis.